# "No filesystem found for scheme s3" when trying to read/write using Apache Beam

Tags: amazon-s3, kotlin, apache-beam

I am starting to use Apache Beam in a project for the first time, and what I am trying to do is read and write Parquet files to and from S3, from an EMR cluster on AWS.

However, each time I try to execute my code, I only get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No filesystem found for scheme s3
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.getFileSystemInternal(FileSystems.java:459)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.match(FileSystems.java:119)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.match(FileSystems.java:140)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.match(FileSystems.java:152)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileIO$MatchAll$MatchFn.process(FileIO.java:636)
```

The documentation does not provide any example, so I have no clue if I have to initialize something anywhere in my code.

I tried to check the Beam source code but, for what I understand, the FileSystems class should register all filesystem modules, and my pom.xml contains the Amazon Web Services Beam module (which in turn brings the AWS S3 module).

The only initialization block that I am doing now is:

```
val options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create()
options.runner = SparkRunner::class.java
val pipeline = Pipeline.create(options)
...
val runner = SparkRunner.fromOptions(options)
runner.run(pipeline).waitUntilFinish()
```

Spark starts to run correctly, up until the exception.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to create a custom class for AWS credentials that will represent Apache Beam job options.

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
YourCustomOptionsClass options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create().as(YourCustomOptionsClass.class);
options.as(AwsOptions.class).setAwsCredentialsProvider(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds));
options.as(AwsOptions.class).setAwsRegion(region);
options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
options.setProject(projectId);

options.set... (All other options you need)
```

In my code YourCustomOptionClass is implementing S3Options and DataflowPipelineOptions

To find out more about creating custom options check out apache beam documentation
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#configuring-pipeline-options

Other full example that may help:

https://github.com/asaharland/beam-pipeline-examples/tree/master/src/main/java/com/harland/example/batch